# gnuplot smooth frequency with conditional formatting

Tags: plot, gnuplot, frequency, palette

Creating a normiles stack diagram works perfectly fine, now I want to use a different color for the boxes fitting in a specific range.

For this, I adopted the following:

```
set palette maxcolors 2
set palette defined  ( 0 '#C0504D', 1 '#00B059')

plot dataFileCity using (rounded(stringcolumn(1) eq city  ? $2 : NaN)):
(100 / (bin_width * STATS_records)):($2 > 1300 ? 0 : 1) 
smooth frequency with boxes palette
```

If column 2 has a value highter than 1300 I would like to have a different color.

Which is based on:
[Normalized histograms in gnuplot with added function plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839967/normalized-histograms-in-gnuplot-with-added-function-plot)
And 
[Color bars in different colors for some specific values in Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808335/color-bars-in-different-colors-for-some-specific-values-in-gnuplot)

However, I am afriad that the smooth frequency makes the thing not work. How can I pass the value such that is creates the a different color?

Comment: You can't mix smoothing and variable colors. If you need to check if the final value is above 1300, then you can write the smoothed values to a temporary file with `set table` <http://stackoverflow.com/q/18346952/2604213>. If you need to check if a single value of all values contributing to the sum is above 1300 you must use an external tool.

Comment: It concerns the x-axis, so for all contributions to all x-values below <1300 I want to have specific color, the same for >1300.

Let me study `set table in the mean while

Answer (score 0):

I know this is nearly 8 years old, but I had the same issue and based on Christoph's comment above I was able to figure out a way.

Below is the graph I wanted:

[image]

However selecting certain rows only by way of the ternary and `NaN` does not play nice with `smooth freq`, and my histogram was wrong (seemed bins were drawn over one another and frequencies weren't as high as they should've been).

This did not work:

```
plot \
    'filename' using ($1 >= 0 ? $1 : NaN) notitle smooth freq with boxes fillcolor rgb "green", \
    'filename' using ($1 <  0 ? $1 : NaN) notitle smooth freq with boxes fillcolor rgb "red"
```

In the manual for gnuplot 5.4.2, this section describes an experimental feature which, combined with `set table`, allowed me to achieve the above graph.

> [EXPERIMENTAL] To select only a subset of the data points for tabulation you can provide an input filter condition (if ) at the end of the command. Note that the input filter may reference data columns that are not part of the output. This feature may change substantially before appearing in a released version of gnuplot.
>
> `plot <file> using 1:2:($4+$5) with table if (strcol(3) eq "Red")`

-- p207 gnuplot v5.4.2 manual

So the approach is:

- Use `set table $my_data_block_green` to set the next plot command to output to the `$my_data_block_green` data block. We'll create one data block for each colour and this is the first.
- Use `plot <file> with table if (<condition_for_green>)` to write to the green data block only rows matching `<condition_for_green>`.
- Use `set table $my_data_block_red` (as in point 1).
- Use `plot <file> with table if (<condition_for_red>)` to write to the red data block only rows matching `<condition_for_red>`.
- Cease writing plot commands to tables with `unset table`.
- Plot as normal, referencing the data blocks instead of `<file>`.

Relevant code (not the full code for graph above):

```
set table $db1
plot <filename> using 7:(1) with table if ($7 >= 0)

set table $db2
plot <filename> using 7:(1) with table if ($7 < 0)

unset table

plot \
    '$db1' using $1:.. .. fillcolor rgb "green", \
    '$db2' using $1:.. .. fillcolor rgb "red"
```

Hope that saves someone a few mins.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @TKF's answer... There is no need to split the `smooth freq` data into two tables.
Instead, plot it into one table and set the color via `lc rgb variable` and by defining an appropriate function.
The following example works for gnuplot>=5.2, with some modifications also with earlier versions.

**Code:**

```
### histogram with split colors
reset session

# create some random test data
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:2000] {
        print sprintf("%g",int(invnorm(rand(0))*100))
    }
set print

stats $Data u 1 nooutput
xmin = STATS_min
xmax = STATS_max
N = 20
myWidth = (xmax-xmin)/N
bin(col) = myWidth*floor(column(col)/myWidth)+myWidth/2.

set boxwidth myWidth
set key noautotitle
set style fill solid 0.3
set grid x,y

set table $Histo
    plot $Data u (bin(1)) smooth freq 
unset table

myColor(col) = column(col)<0 ? 0xff0000 : 0x00cc00

plot $Histo u 1:2:(myColor(1)) w boxes lc rgb var 
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]